# connecting to neo4j HA Cluster

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-ogm, neo4j-ha

**What is the proper way for connecting neo4j HA cluster using neo4j-ogm and allowing high availability and reads scale-out?**

I have seen few solutions that involves haproxy.

the first one is the neo4j [ogm-manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/) that shows how to configure haproxy to transfer connections to the current master. this solution allowing high availability, but **disallowing scale-out reads**.

The second one is Stefan Armbruster blog "[neo4j and haproxy: some best practices and tricks](http://blog.armbruster-it.de/2015/08/neo4j-and-haproxy-some-best-practices-and-tricks/)" about configuring haproxy for routing reads operations for the whole cluster and write operations only for the master server.

I have few problems with Stefan solution:

1. I cannot use bolt protocol, I must use http driver.
2. I'm going to use transactions for all of my queries, and I'm afraid it will cause issues because according to the neo4j developer manual:

   > Open transactions are not shared among members of an HA cluster. Therefore, if you use this endpoint in an HA cluster, you must ensure that all requests for a given transaction are sent to the same Neo4j instance.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, Neo4j OGM does not distinguish between reads and writes and hence is unable to decide whether to send a read request to a slave for example. This feature is on the roadmap, but for now, the safest is to direct all transactions to master.

Comment: Thank you, your answer it's much appreciated. I understand that the current  Neo4j OGM version does not distinguish between reads and writes. I'm trying to find a way to do a work around for enabling my system to scale out reads until this fetcher will be available.